# How to use extended @types in project based on internal modules

Tags: typescript, leaflet, powerbi

I am in need for some guidance to do something that is kinda basic when not using namespaces. I am using in this case `leaflet` (javascript lib for maps) and `leaflet.heat` (leaflet plugin to make heatmaps). Without messing with namespaces/modules, importing them would be just something like it's pointed out [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10859):

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.heat';
```

But, because I am working with Power BI custom visuals, I must follow their way to build the solution, which is to use only internal modules. So to import the lib I added the @types `index.d.ts` file references in `tsconfig.json` and the  `.js` references in `pbiviz.json`.

After the references have been set up, I am able to access the leaflet elements by writing the namespace followed by whatever defined in it's type. E.g. `L.map()`, `L.TileLayer`, etc. But I am unable to access anything that extends the base leaflet module.

I have tried reordering the @types imports, modifying the file to somehow merge in the `L` namespace, importing just like `import 'leaflet.heat';`, but nothing seems to make it recognize the type.

The following code makes the compiler say: [ts] Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    import 'leaflet.heat';
    ...
}
```

This other way complains as well: [ts] Cannot compile modules using option 'out' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.

```
import 'leaflet.heat';
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    ...
}
```

Any ideas of what I could try to make it recognize the type? So far, the workaround I found is to cast it to any, but I don't like it. `(L as any).heatLayer()`

I'm using typescript 2.7.2 and this is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "out": "./.tmp/build/visual.js"
},
"files": [
    ".api/v1.10.0/PowerBI-visuals.d.ts",
    "node_modules/powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils/lib/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/powerbi-visuals-utils-tooltiputils/lib/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/d3/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/geojson/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/leaflet.heat/index.d.ts",
    ...
}
```

Link to the respective `@types`:

- [leaflet](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/leaflet/index.d.ts)
- [leaflet.heat](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/leaflet.heat/index.d.ts)

Answer (score 0):

`powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils` is a very ticklish library. If you're writing pure TypeScript and not integrating external js files, I hope you have a good computer chair because you'll be sitting at the computer for a while before you find some coherent dialog on this issue. You would think there would be more people sharing how they've decoupled their code so src/visual.ts doesn't become a big ball of mud...

Here's the closest I've got powerbi to recognize extended classes:

create a new .ts file (type the following in the class):

```
namespace dev {
    export function foo(): any { }
    export class bar { 
    } 
}
```

don't forget to update the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "out": "./.tmp/build/visual.js"
  },
  "files": [
    ..
    "src/NameOfTsFileHere.ts"
  ]
}
```

in src/visual.ts, the namespace dev should be visible now by referencing:

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    "use strict";

    export class Visual implements IVisual {

        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
            let obj: dev.foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Other things to note:
I do not believe it's possible to reference external libraries from within the new .ts file at this time. If you're using libraries like d3, lodash etc. assume the "dev" namespace is escaped when it's compiled (if your output is ES5), so the window variables won't be available, you'll have to be creative when how you pass references to these libraries around.